# Is it possible to determine what scheduling algorithm is being used to schedule processes in our machine?

Tags: ubuntu, process, scheduling

I am using ubuntu 13.04 on a Intel i7 (first generation) processor. Can i find out how my OS is scheduling processes??

I want to find out whether it is using a Fair share or Priority based algorithm. If so, what can be the possible time slice value for each process and how is the initial process priority decided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default class is time-sharing scheduling unless specifically set. Each process runs via it own priority and class. If no class/prio is specified it will run in SHED_OTHER class with static priority 0. Time slice is dependent on static priority of process; it also depend on process behavior.

Initial process priority is default 0.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Linux provides two separate process scheduling algorithms. One is time-sharing algorithm for fair preemptive scheduling among multiple process; the other is designed for the real-time tasks where absolute priorities are more important than the fairness.In real-time situations system must allow kernel to be preempted to keep dispatch latency low.
    Linux allow only process running in the user mode to be preempted. A process can't be preempted while its running in the kernel mode, even if the real-time process with the high priority is available.
     Hope this will help.